# Error during switch device - XPM

Tags: web8, experience-manager, dd4t

We are using Web 8.1 and DD4T for building websites. Recently we are implementing XPM in your staging environment. XPM is working fine in desktop but when we try switch device and select any device other than desktop, we are getting following error in browser console.

> `http://web8.cms.com/WebUI/Editors/DevicePreview/Proxy/DeviceEmulatorProxy.aspx?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fen%3Ftoken%3D358bd0d0c5fb6b&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(iPhone%3B%20CPU%20iPhone%20OS%205_0%20like%20Mac%20OS%20X)%20AppleWebKit%2F534.46%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Version%2F5.1%20Mobile%2F9A334%20Safari%2F7534.48.3` **500 (Internal Server Error)**

Getting 500 error from above URL (`http://web8.cms.com/WebUI/Editors/DevicePreview/Proxy/DeviceEmulatorProxy.aspx`)

Also, when I checked in the server I don't find `DeviceEmulatorProxy.aspx` in the path. It is missing because we are using Web 8?

*Note: I have changed the actual domain names above URLs for the obvious reasons.*

Comment: Your URL's are not accessible, we need more info on the specific errors/error logs you encountered while switching the device inside XPM to help you in resolving your issue

Comment: @Rajesh Apologies for late response. I don't see specific error other that 500 response from DeviceEmulatorProxy.aspx. Also as I mentioned DeviceEmulatorProxy.aspx file itself not present in server. I believe the XPM installation is in complete.